# Macro to save file name and remove attachment

Tags: microsoft-outlook

We use Outlook 2007. We are constantly pressured to keep the size of our inboxes and personal folders down.  When ever I send a message with attachments, I always save the file name at the bottom of the e-mail and remove it from the e-mail before moving it to a personal folder.  This way I have traceability of what files were sent, but does not have the file size due to the attachment.  How do I write a macro to do this for me when there are multiple attachments?